# A PHP Error was encountered : Undefined property: Login::$admin

Tags: codeigniter-3

I want to make login in my website with codeigniter but i got error it say Undefined property: Login::$admin and Call to a member function check_login() on null in the login.php - controller

I try to watch youtube but i can't find the answare please help

Admin.php - model

```
//fungsi cek session
function logged_id()
{
    return $this->session->userdata('user_id');
}

//fungsi check login
function check_login($table, $field1, $field2)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->where($field1);
    $this->db->where($field2);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Dashboard - controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    //load model admin
    $this->load->model('Admin');
}

public function index()
{
    if($this->admin->logged_id())
    {

        $this->load->view("Dashboard");         

    }else{

        //jika session belum terdaftar, maka redirect ke halaman login
        redirect("Login");

    }
}

public function logout()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('login');
}
```

Login.php - controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    //load model admin
    $this->load->model('Admin');
}

public function index()
{

        if($this->admin->logged_id())
        {
            //jika memang session sudah terdaftar, maka redirect ke halaman dahsboard
            redirect("Dashboard");

        }else{

            //jika session belum terdaftar

            //set form validation
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

            //set message form validation
            $this->form_validation->set_message('required', '<div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top: 3px">
                <div class="header"><b><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> {field}</b> harus diisi</div></div>');

            //cek validasi
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

            //get data dari FORM
            $username = $this->input->post("username", TRUE);
            $password = MD5($this->input->post('password', TRUE));

            //checking data via model
            $checking = $this->admin->check_login('tbl_users', array('username' => $username), array('password' => $password));

            //jika ditemukan, maka create session
            if ($checking != FALSE) {
                foreach ($checking as $apps) {

                    $session_data = array(
                        'user_id'   => $apps->id_user,
                        'user_name' => $apps->username,
                        'user_pass' => $apps->password,
                    );
                    //set session userdata
                    $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);

                    redirect('dashboard/');

                }
            }else{

                $data['error'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top: 3px">
                    <div class="header"><b><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ERROR</b> username atau password salah!</div></div>';
                $this->load->view('login', $data);
            }

        }else{

            $this->load->view('login');
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$this->admin->` with `$this->Admin->` in both Dashboard and Login controllers as your modal class name is Admin and those call are case sensitive.